# How to rename slack app home tab and change the order of opening tabs

Tags: java, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am looking for alternative ways to customize the slack home tab, have a couple of questions:

1. How to rename the home tab button?
2. If we click on the app it first open home tab, can we change it to the message tab? if yes, how?
3. Can we add custom tabs in slack apps?

Find an image for reference: [slack app opens home tab first, I want to change it to the message tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1Z3V.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Right now it's not possible to rename tabs or add custom tabs. We stuck only with Home, Messages and About tabs.
About your second question, checkout this link:
https://api.slack.com/reference/deep-linking#open_app_home.